# Error 512: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server

my `SQL` is:

```
SELECT DB1.IdUtente
        ,DB2.Gruppo
        ,DB1.Username
        ,DB1.Psw

        ,CASE WHEN DB1.RagioneSociale IS NOT NULL
                    AND DB1.RagioneSociale <> ''
            THEN DB1.RagioneSociale
            ELSE DB1.Cognome + ' ' + DB1.Nome
            END AS Nominativo

        ,DB1.Indirizzo + ' - ' + DB1.Cap+ ' ' + DB1.Citta + '(' + DB1.Provincia + ')' AS IndirizzoCompleto
        ,DB1.Telefono + ' ' + DB1.Email AS Contatti

        ,(SELECT DISTINCT COUNT (*)
            FROM DB3
            WHERE DB3.IdAttivazione = DB1.IdUtente
            ) AS NumeroAccessi

        ,(SELECT DB4.NumTarga
            FROM DB4
            WHERE DB4.IdUtente = DB1.IdUtente
            ) AS NumeroTarghe

        ,DB1.DataRegistrazione
        ,DB1.DataScadenza
        ,DB1.Attivo 
FROM DB1
    INNER JOIN DB2
        ON DB1.IdGruppo = DB2.IdGruppo 
WHERE DB1.Demo = 0
ORDER BY DB1.RagioneSociale
```

Why i receive this error from sql server?

> Error 512: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

What am i wrong?

Sorry for bad english.

Thanks for any help

Kind Regards

M.W.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT (*)` -> remove the `distinct` keyword, it's redundant. As for the error, your second subquery must be returning more then one value...

Comment: why i only want get one column from DB4 that is NumTarga....

Comment: You are getting one column, but multiple rows.

Comment: Ok but alone it returns one row with value.....

Comment: In that case, that should not happen.

Comment: Ja, but it's happen... i will try into other way.. and i'll put here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub-selects should be rewritten as `join`s even if your code was working without issue.

If you do this and actually do some testing across your whole dataset you will see where your duplication is coming from, which is giving you more than one row and causing the error you are seeing:

```
SELECT DB1.IdUtente
        ,DB2.Gruppo
        ,DB1.Username
        ,DB1.Psw

        ,CASE WHEN DB1.RagioneSociale IS NOT NULL
                    AND DB1.RagioneSociale <> ''
            THEN DB1.RagioneSociale
            ELSE DB1.Cognome + ' ' + DB1.Nome
            END AS Nominativo

        ,DB1.Indirizzo + ' - ' + DB1.Cap+ ' ' + DB1.Citta + '(' + DB1.Provincia + ')' AS IndirizzoCompleto
        ,DB1.Telefono + ' ' + DB1.Email AS Contatti

        ,DB3.NumeroAccessi

        -- Somewhere in your data you will have at least two rows with different values in this field.
        ,DB4.NumTarga AS NumeroTarghe

        ,DB1.DataRegistrazione
        ,DB1.DataScadenza
        ,DB1.Attivo 
FROM DB1
    INNER JOIN DB2
        ON DB1.IdGruppo = DB2.IdGruppo
    INNER JOIN (SELECT IdAttivazione
                    ,COUNT(*) as NumeroAccessi
                FROM DB3
                GROUP BY IdAttivazione
                ) DB3
        ON DB3.IdAttivazione = DB1.IdUtente
    INNER JOIN DB4
        ON DB4.IdUtente = DB1.IdUtente
WHERE DB1.Demo = 0
ORDER BY DB1.RagioneSociale
```